# How can I farm Inferno Ponies as a solo Monk?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

I'm currently trying to do inferno ponies with monk but getting melted fairly often.

Are there any monks out there who can solo farm ponies in inferno? Can you share what stats you have? Stuff like - what your resist all; armour; hp; dps; loh; etc...

I'm guessing you're using shield instead of dw?

Answer (score 4):

Solo farming ponies is HARD, and currently imo not worth the effort.  The loot you get there is equivalent to act 3/4 of inferno and act 3 is a heck lot easier and with a lot more rare groups to fight through.

Having said that, if you truly want to solo farm ponies, you'll need some very very good monk gear (each piece of armor will cost tens of millions to buy):

Weapon/Shield stats:

1. No less than 30k hp
2. 1200+ resist all (one with everything, stack one element of your choice)
3. 4000+ armor (with mantra of evasion + hard target)
4. 40%+ dodge (with mantra of evasion)
5. 25k+ dps (~20% crit, ~200% crit damage)
6. 1k+ life on hit (1.5k+ preferably)
7. 30%+ block chance for (3k+ reduction)
8. 2+ attacks per second

Dual wield stats:

1. No less than 30k hp
2. 700+ resist all
3. 5k+ armor (more dex = more armor)
4. 50%+ dodge (with passive skill)
5. 35k+ dps
6. 1.5k+ life on hit
7. 2+ attacks per second

Ponies hit VERY hard and they are very fast, be prepared to take a ton of damage even with those stats, and some groups are just impossible (especially invulnerable minions since you need lots of targets to trigger LoH).  With that gear, you can pretty easily walk through act3 to build up 5 stacks and then eviscerate Cydea and Azmodan with no problems for 2 boss drops and many many rares mob groups.